# Python logging configuration with empty parentheses in loggers

Tags: python, django, logging

In one Django app I've met this logging configuration (in `dictConfig`-format). My problem is that I don't understand what empty parentheses stands for in specified loggers:

```
LOGGING = {
...
    'loggers': {
        '()': {
            'handlers': ['console']
        },
    }
...
}
```

Ok, documentation makes pretty clear what empty parentheses means in configuring handlers:

> a callable which is called with a configuration dictionary and which returns the instantiated object. This is signalled by an absolute import path to the factory being made available under the special key '()'.

But in my example `loggers` doesn't contain any callable. And also, semantic meaning of `loggers` (afaiu) is to specify areas of responsibility, but what is `()` in this context? Looks like some legacy typo or maybe I'm missing something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have seen similar code myself, somewhere.... I have a vague feeling I might have assumed it was invalid, and changed it.

After looking at the source code again, I don't think it is valid. It will never get used. Not tested this theory.

If it was something legacy, would expect to see something documented in legacy documentation, however I looked at the following (quickly) and didn't see anything:

- https://www.red-dove.com/python_logging.html
- https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0282/